# How can I add a second smaller tcolorbox on the lower right corner of the frame of a bigger tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, overlays, frame

I want to achieve what you can see in the attached picture. I succeed so far with my MWE to add a title to the upper left corner. How can I add the second tcolorbox in the lower right corner of the main box?
The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=15cm, enhanced,title=Title, attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift=-2mm},boxed title style={size=small,colback=blue}]
        Some relatively long text ...
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591386/two-boxes-with-tcolorbox)

Comment: I am afraid no because I need a tcolorbox not just a tikz path with a node inside. I would like to change the fill color, to have text alignment, all the advantages that tcolorbox offers. I know that some of them can be done using tikz, but tcolorbox is much more convenient for boxes and text inside them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's too correct, but you can add a `tcolorbox` inside a `node` inside a `overlay` option. In this cae you will have to manually control how much vertical space is added to the original `tcolorbox` to prevent that the extra box covers the text.

A little example which worked for me.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]    
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=15cm, enhanced,title=Title, attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift=-2mm},boxed title style={size=small,colback=blue}, enlarge bottom by=2cm, 
    overlay={\node[anchor=east] at ([xshift=-1cm]frame.south east) {\begin{tcolorbox}[width=4cm, title=ABC]{Some large text ...}\end{tcolorbox}};}]
        Some relatively long text ...
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]